# Fill Parent Container with react-native-chart-kit Chart (React Native, Expo)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-chart-kit

I am using [`react-native-chart-kit`](https://github.com/indiespirit/react-native-chart-kit/) in a React Native Expo app to render charts. The example provided in the docs work fine

**Problem:** In my app, the chart is needed to fill a parent container, but it appears that the chart must have the `height` props as a fixed value.

```
<LineChart
    height={221}
    ...
/>
```

Attempting to set the `height` value to `100%` or removing the definition will result in a NaN-related error

> Invariant Violation: [.....,"y1":"<>","x2":"375","y2":"<>"}] is not usable as a native method argument

Is there a solution to this problem? Thank you!

**Working Example based on Docs**

```
export default class Chart extends Component {

    render() {
        const data = {
            datasets: [{
                data: [
                    Math.random() * 100,
                    Math.random() * 100,
                    Math.random() * 100,
                    Math.random() * 100,
                    Math.random() * 100,
                    Math.random() * 100
                ]
            }]
        }

        return (
            <LineChart 
                data={data}
                width={Dimensions.get('window').width}
                height={221}
                yAxisLabel={'$'}
                chartConfig={{
                    backgroundColor: '#e26a00',
                    backgroundGradientFrom: '#fb8c00',
                    backgroundGradientTo: '#ffa726',
                    decimalPlaces: 2, // optional, defaults to 2dp
                    color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
                    style: {
                        borderRadius: 16
                    }
                }}
                bezier
                style={{
                    marginVertical: 8,
                    borderRadius: 16
                }}
            />
        )
    }

}
```

---

**@hong develop**

The `react-native-chart-kit` component `<LineChart />` can be a child of another Component whose height is variable. So `<LineChart />` does not necessary have the height given by `Dimensions.get('window').height;`. For example,

```
render() {
    <View>
        <Header />
        { this.props.foo ? this.renderFoo() : null }
        <View>
            <LineChart 
                ...
            />
        </View>
    </View>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of `height` is the `number`. Therefore, `string values` are not allowed. If you want to replace what you're trying to do, you can use this.

```js
const screenheight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
<LineChart
    height={screenheight}
    ...
/>
```

As you can see by referring to [this document,](https://github.com/indiespirit/react-native-chart-kit/blob/master/src/line-chart.js) the chart cannot be seen without setting the height. Because the width and height are set by the set value, you must write down the value unconditionally.

Comment: Is there a way to get the height dimension of the parent of `<LineChart/>`? Updated the question for a possible scenario where we cannot use `Dimensions.get('window').height` as there will be other components above and/or below it.

Comment: @Nyxynyx As you can see from the document I've linked, there is no default value to receive and set the height from the parent. Make sure that the height value is received and set.

Comment: So was there a definitive solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer here: https://github.com/indiespirit/react-native-chart-kit/issues/506#issuecomment-917564118

You can use the onlayout prop to get the components height and width and set that to the height and width of the chart. Here is a description of the prop https://reactnative.dev/docs/layoutevent

```
 const [chartParentWidth, setChartParentWidth] = useState(0);
 const [chartParentHeight, setChartParentHeight] = useState(0);

<View onLayout={({ nativeEvent }) => {
                setChartParentWidth(nativeEvent.layout.width)
                setChartParentHeight(nativeEvent.layout.height)

            }}>
```